# How to widen the upper body (make distance between shoulders slightly higher)?

Tags: muscle, shoulders, upper-body-workout, bones, skeleton

I just wanna know if there are any daily routines or exercises that - do not necessarily build muscles but in fact - make the distance between your shoulders higher and eventually widen the very upper body .

Pushing those blue points outside. Any suggestions? Exercises, workouts, stretches ...

[image]

Comment: Lots of wide grip pull ups and wide push ups are some exercises to build up your upper back and strengthen your lats. This *(in addition to core exercises and lower body fat)* should reduce the width of your mid-region, which will give you the V-shape you're referring to.

Comment: I understand you @Kneel-Before-ZOD, but I'm wanting to widen the upper part of my upper body (not to narrow the lower part of my upper body) because I have a big head, and with wide distance as I've been showing, i'll get a more propotional shape, thank you though

Comment: *How about a reconstructive surgery?* :p Seriously though, it's kinda improbable to widen your shoulder without affecting your lower torso. Increasing your delts, traps, and chest will give you a bigger frame; however, I don't think it would achieve the look you're going for. I'm looking forward to some answers.

Comment: Overhead press and lateral raises wouldn't hurt ([here's a guide](http://stronglifts.com/overhead-press/) to the press). They would build your shoulder caps and help give the appearance of wider shoulders. I've heard that heavy trap work will make your shoulders appear more narrow, so stay away from the [useless] shoulder shrugs. However, some things you cannot drastically change, such as shoulder width, ankle and wrist diameter. You'll not find an exercise that adds 5 inches to your shoulder width because exercise doesn't elongate your bones. Some things you're just born with.

Answer (score 5):

Exercises that build muscle in your upper arms, shoulders, and upper back can make your shoulders *look* wider, but they won't change the actual distance between your joints. Although weight-bearing exercise can increase bone density, the basic geometry of your skeleton isn't really altered by exercise. There's no exercise that will make you taller or have longer arms, either, for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, regular physical fitness routines will indeed make a difference on bone structure and growth as well as muscle mass giving net result as an increase in shoulder distance. The younger you are as you begin, the greater the effect will be. Specifically, weight training and other anaerobic and high impact routines will have the greatest effect on both bone and muscle growth. This, however, needs to be consistent training over a long period of time in order to realize the effects long-term.

The goal is to naturally increase your growth hormone (GH) levels as osteocytes and osteoblasts are stimulated by GH and by mechanotransduction. Actual bone length may not be effected at all and may have more to do with genetics. See my other answer [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29051/relation-between-upper-body-workout-and-wrist-size) (relating to wrist size, but also relevant for other bones and muscles) for a detailed explanation. HINT: Read the section entitled "Detailed Explanation of Bone Growth".

Diet also plays an important role. You need to have enough protein as well as many other nutrients in order to support and maintain the muscles and bones.

Just about any upper body workout involving the shoulders, chest, or upper back overtime will give the impression of a greater shoulder distance and increase bone density and growth overtime. You should, however, not endeavor to make this your main goal. Ideally, overall health and fitness and proportionate body strength should be the main goal to strive for. Besides, as your leg and glut muscles are the largest in your body, they will therefore have the greatest net effect in increasing your GH levels.

[Relation between upper body workout and wrist size](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29051/relation-between-upper-body-workout-and-wrist-size)